# How to convert string to json using net.sf.json (json-taglib-2.2.2)

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java EE and JSON..

I searched on Stackoverflow, but I found "How to convert string to json" using gson and other jar files, then I searched on GOOGLE and sourceforge to find if there is any constructor like

```
JSONObject jsobj= new JSONObject(stringJSONValue);
```

But there is only parameter-less constructor and boolean constructor.
Can Anyone please suggest me a easier way to achieve the task in json-taglib..

If it is duplicate question please suggest me the original one.

Comment: Uh, how do you convert a string to JSON?  JSON *is* a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [JSONSerializer.toJSON](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONSerializer.html#toJSON%28java.lang.Object%29).  It will accept a JSON-formatted string and return to you a JSON object.